# How can I get current_user in Devise SessionsController#destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a custom Devise Session Controler. I need to register the user when Logout, for this I need the current_user helper method.

```
include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
class Api::UsersController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    super

    p current_user # Object user - OK!

  end

  def destroy
    super

    puts current_user # nil - I need this

  end

end
```

How do I get current user in the method destroy ?

Comment: can you swap the order?  `puts current_user; destroy`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a rails callback.

```
include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
class Api::UsersController < Devise::SessionsController
    before_destroy: :do_something

    def create
        super
        p current_user # Object user - OK!
    end

    def destroy
    end

    def do_something
        current_user
    end
end
```

Do whatever you want in the "do_something" method.