# Get current user in Devise custom session controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

I already found the same question here: [How can I get current_user in Devise SessionsController#destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039589/how-can-i-get-current-user-in-devise-sessionscontrollerdestroy), but this ins't working and because i don't have 50+ reputation, i can't ask for the guy who answered that question

Ruby version: '2.6.5', Rails Version: '6.0.3.2'

this is the session controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

include Devise::Controllers::Helpers
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  # before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :get_current_user, only: [:destroy]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    if !session[:return_to].blank?
      render json: { logged: false }
    else
      render json: { logged: true, user: current_user }
    end
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    p "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    p current_user # Nil
    puts current_user # returns empty
    p "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    # super
  end

  protected

  def get_current_user
    p current_user # nil
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end
end
```

Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'show/users', to: 'development#index' 
  get 'show/:id', to: 'development#show'
  delete 'delete/:id', to: 'development#destroy'
  
  get 'login', to: 'login#index'
  get 'sign_up', to: 'register#index'

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }
  root 'home#index'
end
```

My request:

```
  axios
    .delete("http://localhost:8081/users/sign_out")
    .then((resource) => {
      console.log(resource);
      // window.location = "/";
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

I want current_user to be able to sign_out a user logged

Comment: why you have commented `super` method in destroy, it will log out the user

Comment: You can see their implementation of it here: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

Comment: I commented because this happens when i make the request https://imgur.com/04dCLGB.png , I was trying a different approach

Answer (score 0):

I manged to make it work.

In devise.rb (project-folder/config/initializers), i changed the:

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

to:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Of course i had to change the request to .get